# Use angular and docker when developing

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I tried to use docker to build a development environment, when nginx visited the angular program, it returned 502

I use docker to build a development environment. When the container is started, I can use `http://localhost/api` to access the api service, or use `http://localhost:27017` to access mongodb, but when I visit "http://localhost", an error of 502 appears

docker-compose

```yaml
# docker-compose up -d
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    working_dir: /web
    networks:
      - overlay
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - admin
      - api

  admin:
    image: node:14
    working_dir: /web/apps/admin
    command: bash -c "npm i && npm run start"
    networks:
      - overlay
    expose:
      - 4200
    volumes:
      - ./apps/admin:/web/apps/admin
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    image: node:14
    working_dir: /web/apps/api
    command: bash -c "npm i && npm run start:dev"
    expose:
      - 3000
    networks:
      - overlay
    volumes:
      - ./apps/api:/web/apps/api
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - overlay
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo_data:/data/db

networks:
  overlay:
```

nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api:3000;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://admin:4200;
    }
}
```

The repository is here: https://github.com/januwA/ng-nest-admin

I don't know what went wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, `apps/admin` is a git submodule, but there is no URL specified for it, so we can’t pull it…

Comment: @Auktis Sorry, but I didn't pay attention, I have updated the repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add development configuration to angular.json

```json
...
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": 4200,
            "disableHostCheck": true
          },
        },
```

After restarting the container, nginx works normally